# FME batch processing results filename "NULL"

Tags: fme-form

I have a FME workspace and a workspace runner. The workspace reads several sources (PostGIS & Shapefile) but only one is batched. In other words, all shapefiles in one folders are all analysed against files from other sources, which remain the same on every run.

My problem is that the writer has a parameter "fme_basename" as the shapefile name value, but when I run the workspace runner, only the first shapefile gets the correct name (in this case L42213D) but the second is "NULL". Also all the rest of the batched files result as NULL so the second file is just overwritten until the process ends. This worked in my other workspace which was almost similar, but I can't get it working here...

Comment: Are you using Dynamic schema import? https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Dynamic-Workflow-Tutorial-Destination-Schema-as-a-Mirror-Image-of-the-Source-Dataset

Answer (score 1):

Im not absolutely sure what is happening in your workflow from your description, but try to set the properties of your reader in the child workspace to Merge Feature Type to Merge Filter = * , Filter Tye = Wildcard. See image below.
[image]